# Python: Issues with writing comma delimited data to a .csv file

Tags: python, csv, delimiter, ohlc

**Goal:**

1. Read stock price data in from a `.csv file`
2. resample it
3. finally print the output to a new `.csv file` whereby **all columns are comma delimited.**

**Issues:**

Currently, the program can 1) read in the data and 2) resample it, but when printing to an output `.csv` there are **no comma delimiters.** Furthermore, the column headers are **not** printed on the same first line.

**Input data sample:**

*Columns of interest: First column (which is date/time), second column (bid price), and fourth column (ask price).

```
20210602 22:02:00,3.07,50,3.086,50
20210602 22:03:00,3.07,50,3.087,50
20210602 22:04:00,3.071,50,3.087,50
20210602 22:04:00,3.071,50,3.088,50
20210602 22:05:00,3.07,50,3.088,50
20210602 22:05:00,3.07,50,3.087,50
20210602 22:06:00,3.071,50,3.087,50
```

**Current output:**

```
                     open    high    low      close
Date_time
2021-06-02 22:02:00  3.0790  3.0790  3.0780  3.0780
2021-06-02 22:03:00  3.0785  3.0785  3.0785  3.0785
2021-06-02 22:04:00  3.0790  3.0795  3.0790  3.0795
2021-06-02 22:05:00  3.0790  3.0790  3.0785  3.0785
2021-06-02 22:06:00  3.0790  3.0790  3.0790  3.0790
```

**Expected output:**

```
Date_time,open,high,low,close
2021-06-02 22:02:00,3.0790,3.0790,3.0780,3.0780
2021-06-02 22:03:00,3.0785,3.0785,3.0785,3.0785
2021-06-02 22:04:00,3.0790,3.0795,3.0790,3.0795
2021-06-02 22:05:00,3.0790,3.0790,3.0785,3.0785
2021-06-02 22:06:00,3.0790,3.0790,3.0790,3.0790
```

**Program attempt:**

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

data_frame = pd.read_csv('03-06-21-xngusd.csv',
                         names=['Date_time', 'Bid', 'Bid qty',
                                  'Ask', 'Ask qty'],
                         index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
data_frame.head()

# Resample the data into 1 minute increments
data_ask = data_frame['Ask'].resample('1MIN').ohlc()
data_bid = data_frame['Bid'].resample('1MIN').ohlc()
data_mid = (data_ask + data_bid) / 2

data_mid.head()

# Print the new resample data to a .csv file
original_stdout = sys.stdout # Save reference to original standard output
with open('filename.csv', 'w') as f:
    sys.stdout = f
    print(data_mid)
    sys.stdout = original_stdout
```

Also tried the following code, which only printed the first row and also missed the first column header showing an output of `open, high, low, close`:

```
with open('filename.csv', 'w') as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(data_mid)
```

**Q1.** How can the program be modified to ensure that the output columns are `comma delimited`?

**Q2.** How can the column headers be printed to be on the **same line** at the top of the file?

Comment: you can use `data_frame.to_csv` to create a csv directly from the dataframe. I think that can solve your issues. see also: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and did the job perfectly. If you post your comment as an answer, I can mark it as one. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data_frame.to_csv()` for this. Read about it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).